# Cgroup memory controller

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cgroups

I have done a simple experiment with both v1 and v2 cgroup memory controller on a 4.18 kernel that looks like this.

1. I set the maximum memory limit accordingly. For v1 I write into the memory.limit_in_bytes and for v2 I write into the memory.max file.
2. I move the current bash instance into it (i.e. $$) and start a loop that does only ls. The limit is set to 8M bytes.

   ```
   while [[ 1 ]]; do ls; done
   ```

After a while, the bash instance is terminated due to OOM. I do not understand why is this the case because the ls process will return the memory after it finishes so that it can be reused in the next iteration.

I am missing something?

Thanks,

Comment: interesting problem, but I recommend that you make this as easy as possible for readers to duplicate your process as possible. When you say  *I write into the memory.limit_in_bytes*, give us the exact code to do this. Same for the *memory.max file*. Then, where are you running the while loop from, 1) cmd-line? 2) inside a script? 3) inside a script from crontab? 4) ??? other ?  Please don't reply in comments, but improve your Q with this information. Use the `{}` tool from the edit menu on mouse-selected text to format correctly as code/data/errMsgs. Good luck

Comment: OP, did you ever figure this out? Could you make the changes suggested in the previous comment to help me recreate the issue?